# I added a localization in xcode, removed it and now my storyboard is gone

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, storyboard

So I wanted to try localizing my app. I had one single Storyboard.storyboard in my project folder.

1. I checked the "use base internationalization" checkbox and then xcode did something with my files.
2. I proceeded to add a second Localization
3. Xcode told me it couldn't create some .plist since it already existed.
4. I ended up with two storyboards ("Base" and "English" grouped together), which was very strange since the documentation clearly said I would just have to deal with one set of storyboards (when using base intertationalization) and that the other languages would be strings-files:

   > Base internationalization, a feature introduced in Xcode 4.5, relieves localizers (that is, translators) of the need to modify storyboards and nib files for each language an app supports. Instead, an app has just one set of storyboards or nib files that is localized to the default language; these storyboards and nibs are called the base internationalization. When you add a localization to an app, Xcode generates a strings file for all the text that each storyboard or nib file displays or includes as an accessibility label or hint. Xcode gives the file the name of the storyboard and the extension strings. So if you have a storyboard named MyStoryboard.storyboard, the generated strings file is named MyStoryboard.strings.
5. I removed my newly created localization (english) because this was not what I expected
6. Now all of the storyboards are gone, even though I only deleted one localization

I have two storyboards in my trash now (one "storyboard.storyboard" and one named storyboard*some numbers*.storyboard), but I have no idea 1) which one I should use, and 2) is it supposed to be in some sort of subfolder now since I checked the "base internationalization" option? What about the .plists? I read up on things on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html) but it did a better job on telling me where to click than telling me the purpose of the different files, so I have no idea how to reverse this properly

**Update:**

Now it looks like this when I restart xcode: 
[image: Two base localizations, what does that mean?]

I have no clue where to go from here...

Comment: Try removing all the localizations and then checking off `Use Base Internationalization`, and then adding them all back with the files you want to localize

Comment: After some experimenting I found that if I removed all of them I would be unable to create a localization again, because no resources were marked as localized (using the file inspector). But I couldn't mark them as localized until my project had a localization (xcode complained), which created a deadlock. So after restarting xcode (and getting the above picture) I had to delete all but one language, and then use the File inspector to localize the file, as you described in your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the storyboards in the trash, I would try opening them both up and seeing which is correct. And for using .strings files instead of having to localize the whole storyboard, when using base internationalization you have an option. You can change it by changing the option here under localization (this is under the left pane when you open the storyboard)
[image]

Change the option from interface builder to localizable strings, and you don't have to use the storyboard. The difference is in the interface builder one, you would have to edit all labels and anything you want to localize like you would edit any other storyboard, which can be tedious. The strings file makes it easy by basically giving you a list of whatever text you have in your whole storyboard and letting you change what they say by translating the text, instead of having to edit the whole storyboard file.

Comment: That's an interesting detail. I would have tried it, except that now that I manually moved the storyboard back into my project I cannot localize my project. There are no localizable files to choose when adding a new localization, even though the storyboard is in the project.

Comment: You have to relocalize the storyboard by adding it to the localizations by clicking the check mark in the same pane as in the picture.

Comment: That isn't possible until I can add a localization for the project.

Comment: Do you have localizations added in your project info?

Comment: Like I said, I cannot localize my project any longer. See my first comment

Comment: That's strange. Check if your storyboard is the Main Storyboard in you targets summary and it's under copy bundle resources in build phases

Comment: Yeah it's in those two places :) I updated the question. Anyway, I think this is over my head, I've seriously misunderstood something. Back to the docs...

Comment: I deleted my localize files. Now my localize files not showing. When I click add and select lang resource files list is empty. When I say make localize it shows option NOT AVAILABLE. Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: The only thing I remember was that it was easier to sort this out in the filesystem by reading a guide, instead of using xcode. It's easy to get confused in xcode since it displays project files differently from the file system. At the time I didn't know how to organize the files, I just wanted to explore using the proper tools...