# Is there any way to restore Main.storyboard after deleting it during localization process?

Tags: xcode, localization, storyboard

During localization process I have deleted all localizations and Main.storyboard disappeared. 
Now, there is no way I can add new language (base language).

Is there any way to restore it? Why the hell it is being deleted?

**PS.**

Saw this one: [My storyboard is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706851/i-added-a-localization-in-xcode-removed-it-and-now-my-storyboard-is-gone?rq=1), but my trash is empty, so nothing to restore.

Comment: Do you have a commit before the changes?

Comment: Well, I think this is one of those hard lessons as a developer, that you're going to have to learn. Always commit, often. Having said that, if its not in the trash then its gone. As a last resort, try searching your whole Mac for the file.

Comment: @Tander, yep, you are right: commit, commit and commit AGAIN!

Comment: @Tander, please, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it, 'cause I think its really important to use git for any changes we make.

Comment: Done. Just worded it a little better. I agree source control is very important. I hope you come right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why source control is so important. We have all been down this road before and learnt the hard lesson of not practicing source control and not commiting often as possible. It takes a few minutes to setup and can save you hours / days / weeks. It's saved my butt a few times!