# Prevent automatic localization for unsupported languages

Tags: ios, localization

UIBarButtonItem have identifiers like Cancel, Done and some others which get localized automatically. 
Now, if the device language is set to a language which is not yet supported by the app, I would like to disable this feature, in order to prevent this result of languages mix.
Is this thing possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706851/i-added-a-localization-in-xcode-removed-it-and-now-my-storyboard-is-gone

Comment: casillas - thanks a lot!